# How to deal with Mice coming into the Baby's Room

Tags: pest-control, child-safety, mice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get rid of a mouse in my house?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/how-can-i-get-rid-of-a-mouse-in-my-house)

Our first child is due any day now, and we've got a mouse infestation. We noticed it for the first time at my girlfriend's baby shower (lots of cakes and crumbs out), and since then we've started seeing it more frequently. I say "it", but we suspect more than one of them, based on other people's comments.

This was upgraded from "something to deal with" to "major problem" when my girlfriend found mouse droppings in the baby's room. We've put down poison traps in the kitchen, where the thing's been seen most often, but we're wondering what else we can do.

**Our principal concern is to keep the mice away from the baby's room** (other end of the flat to the kitchen, but it doesn't seem to help). Obviously we'd like them gone completely, but it's terraced accomodation (shared walls), and we can't control our neighbours behaviour.

We're also concerned about leaving poison or traps in the baby room.

Comment: Did you search before posting? The problem of mice has been covered before - http://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=mice

Comment: Sure, but all of those are about keeping them out *completely*, and while we'll try, it may not be practical due to our neighbours, and the old rented accomodation not allowing us to bring down cupboards, etc. This is about keeping them away from "high-value" rooms like the nursery.

Comment: see also http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6504/how-can-i-remove-mice-from-my-house

Comment: Lots of the traps listed in the linked answers are non-poisonous, some are even non-lethal, which seems like a good solution when you have children around and don't like the idea of killing mice.

Comment: Keep in mind that an infant won't be crawling around on the floor for many months.  Not to say you shouldn't be cautious about putting poison out near a baby, but be realistic about his/her (in)ability to get into anything for at least 3-6 months.  Or, get a cat.

Answer (score 5):

If you look carefully the problem may be worse than you estimate.Remove drawers from kitchen cabinets and check inside for droppings.Check the lower shelves of cabinets and any where food is stored.Try to eliminate food sources,crumbs,pet food etc. should be cleaned up and stored in sealed containors.I would contact the property owner and the local health dept.In multi unit dwellings treating one unit doesn't stop the problem.You could try an plug in electronic pest controller although I don't know if they are available in your area.They emit a tone that the pests don't like but people don't hear.It would eliminate chemical exposure to the baby.Keeping the mice out of the babies room is only part of the solution as you may contact the mouse feces and then handle the baby.

Answer (score 2):

**Call an exterminator, or if you rent, insist your landlord call an exterminator.**

Personally, I feel a mouse infestation where they are in the main areas of your house crosses the line from "pest annoyance" to "serious health issue." There are of course many things you can do on your own to repel or even eliminate mice, but if you have a baby on the way, you need the problem solved *correctly*, and *quickly.*

Therefore this is one time when I would definitely get a professional's help.

Answer (score 2):

3 basic things to do:

- get rid of food access (put cereal in plastic tubs, grains in glass jars, etc.)
- block access (plug all holes in the structure...permanantly, if you can...otherwise use stainless steel wool)
- trap existing mice (I'm a fan of the glue traps...though they may not be the most humane, they do work)

Unfortunately, in a shared structure, #1 and #2 are hard to do completely. I'd probably consider the exterminator as well (as the landlord can have them do the entire building...not just your unit).