# Method to catch multiple mice?

Tags: pest-control, mice

I have a mouse problem in my house. I have put out mouse traps and they have been mostly successful. Five mice have been caught within a week. My predicament is that there are still mice and I would like a method that I can use to catch multiple mice with the same trap so I don't have to keep checking/setting them all the time.

NOTE: I am open to either fatal/live traps.

Comment: Dealing with the source and food supply of the mice would be more effective. The sooner you do that, the fewer mice you'll have to trap. Just pointing out that while individual traps can be a pain, it should be pretty short-term. There's an average of 6-8 babies per litter, which should give you an idea of how many you should expect to catch. They can also breed between 5 and 10 litters per year, which is why it's important to cut off entrances and food ASAP. :)

Comment: There are lots of traps that can catch multiple mice. I think the answer to this is to visit your local big box store and browse the pesticide and trap isle. See also the question about [How can I remove mice from my house](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/6504/2196).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try searching "*mouse bucket trap*". There's a ton of different variations, so I'm not going to go into too much detail. But basically it's a bucket, a ramp, some peanut butter, and a rotating mechanism.

[image: mouse bucket trap]

If you want to kill the mice, put some antifreeze (or other poison) in the bucket. If you're looking for less lethal, leave the bucket empty, or put in some wood chips or similar.

Notice that I said "*less lethal*". If you leave mice in the bucket too long, they will get hungry. And mice have no qualms about going cannibal.

Comment: Without water in the bottom, you may need a surprisingly tall bucket. See [video of mice escaping bucket](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4PaGvAhV9I)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick That guy should patent that device!

Answer (score 1):

1. Poison (Warferin or similar, aka D-CON)
2. Buy more traps.  I bought a 10-pack, and had them lined up to get multi-catch.

The bucket traps take up a lot of space, don't work in low-ceilinged areas, and require that you not disturb the ramp; even then the mouse often jumps while the soda can is turning.

Comment: Warfarin and other poisons will allow the mice to be eaten by those animals further up the food chain, poisoning them also. I don't especially mind if a raccoon, opossum, or other such vermin take a dirt nap, but I would hate to see an eagle, puma, wolf, or someones pet dog or cat meet their maker unnecessarily.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Warferin is actually a targeted rodenticide, and does not poison non-rodent species:  http://pmep.cce.cornell.edu/profiles/extoxnet/pyrethrins-ziram/warfarin-ext.html

Comment: unfortunately you are wrong. Even the article you linked to shows that, did you read it? Warfarin is a blood thinner that will poison **any** animal that ingests it, including humans. Granted, in the concentration marketed for rodent control, a larger animal would have to ingest more for it to be lethal. The (incorrect) presumption that the rodent will bleed out prior to being eaten by another animal is the misplaced reasoning behind marketing that declares it to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ranch or farm supply store. Just bought a live trap for $7 and it held up to 4 mice. Took a few days bc they were leery, but the peanut butter buffet won. We took them to a field. Note: there was lots of pb for them, but check few times daily. .  They ovrrheat quickly and can die. Problem is the scent on the trap for multi use.