# Help getting rid of a mice

Tags: pest-control

6 days ago, I saw a mouse run down my hall and I almost had a heart attack! It was 2:30am and I just got home from work. I knew I wouldn’t sleep if I didn’t set traps, which I had none, so I drove to Walmart at 2:30 in the morning and bought 16 snap traps! Placed 8 of them with peanut butter in the kitchen, dining room, bathroom, my bedroom, my daughters bedroom and our spare room. Yet have caught nothing and none of the traps have been touched, so I know this mouse isn’t going near them!!! Well, just a little while ago, I saw it going from my living room to my dining room! I need to catch this thing before I have a break down lol I am terribly afraid, yes, even of a little mouse! Does anyone have any idea why this is not working or what else I can do?? Please help, just want it gone and not think about this anymore!! Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have any pets in the house?

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/6504/74694

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic as pest control has nothing to do with home improvement. See the [help], and specifically [on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for info on what's on-topic here.

Comment: @TylerH well if the house has pests and a person gets rid of them - I would call that home improvement; then again I never met roach [MIB] he might not agree.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off with a piece of cheese - also traps that capture are better than the slam and decapitate. I never had any luck with peanut butter - cheese works well.

1: Do you live in an Apartment or a Separate residence?

If Apartment , Town home or Condo the issue is that you could have an entry way from one unit to the other that you will need to close off - I had an apartment and behind the stove where the power cord was there was a hole in the wall .. I taped it up and no more mouse.

2: You will need to clean the home thoroughly looking for anything and everything that the mouse can get into for food - including open boxes of cereal in the pantry.

You can nickname the mouse and it might help with you being terrified - yes a bit light - hearted .

Comment: True fact, I was sleeping in the office and heard one clattering across the drop ceiling.  An exhaustive search of the office turned up two mayonnaise packets which had been shredded open and nibbled.  It was the only food in the entire place.  That's all it takes.  Obviously they will go for this broke-into food before they touch what's in a trap.